Видео на сайте laravel не перематывается
Недавно начал изучать программирование и столкнулся с такой проблемой: когда видео подгружается, оно воспроизводится, но при перемотке попросту возвращается в начало. Сайт пишу на Laravel. С чем это может быть связано?
<video v-if="videoPath" class="video-js vjs-theme-fantasy" data-setup="{}" controls>
    <source :src="videoPath" type="video/mp4">
</video>

Видео передаю таким образом. В videoPath попадает путь к файлу

А в чем тут вина Laravel У вас здесь уже сденерированный HTML.
